# fakebackend interceptor error message: "Username "undefined" is already taken"

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I'm following this [tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/22/angular-8-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial) on implementing a simple signup/login feature with a fakebackend interceptor. So far I just have built the signup component, the user model and the service with the corresponding endpoints matching the fake API. But when I send the credentials to the server I get this error: `error: {message: "Username "undefined" is already taken"}` as if no credentials at all were sent...

The fakebackend:

```
    ...The imports...
    
// array in local storage for registered users
    let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];
    
    @Injectable()
    export class FakeBackendInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            const { url, method, headers, body } = request;
    
            // wrap in delayed observable to simulate server api call
            return of(null)
                .pipe(mergeMap(handleRoute))
                .pipe(materialize()) // call materialize and dematerialize to ensure delay even if an error is thrown (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/648)
                .pipe(delay(500))
                .pipe(dematerialize());
    
            function handleRoute() {
                switch (true) {
                    case url.endsWith('/users/register') && method === 'POST':
                        return register();
                    case url.endsWith('/users/authenticate') && method === 'POST':
                        return authenticate();
                    case url.endsWith('/users') && method === 'GET':
                        return getUsers();
                    case url.match(/\/users\/\d+$/) && method === 'GET':
                        return getUserById();
                    case url.match(/\/users\/\d+$/) && method === 'DELETE':
                        return deleteUser();
                    default:
                        // pass through any requests not handled above
                        return next.handle(request);
                }
            }
    
            // route functions
    
            function register() {
                const user = body
    
                if (users.find(x => x.username === user.username)) {
                    return error('Username "' + user.username + '" is already taken')
                }
    
                user.id = users.length ? Math.max(...users.map(x => x.id)) + 1 : 1;
                users.push(user);
                localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
    
                return ok();
            }
    
            function authenticate() {
                const { username, password } = body;
                const user = users.find(x => x.username === username && x.password === password);
                if (!user) return error('Username or password is incorrect');
                return ok({
                    id: user.id,
                    username: user.username,
                    firstName: user.firstName,
                    lastName: user.lastName,
                    token: 'fake-jwt-token'
                })
            }
    
            function getUsers() {
                if (!isLoggedIn()) return unauthorized();
                return ok(users);
            }
    
            function getUserById() {
                if (!isLoggedIn()) return unauthorized();
    
                const user = users.find(x => x.id == idFromUrl());
                return ok(user);
            }
    
            function deleteUser() {
                if (!isLoggedIn()) return unauthorized();
    
                users = users.filter(x => x.id !== idFromUrl());
                localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
                return ok();
            }
    
            // helper functions
    
            function ok(body?) {
                return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body }))
            }
    
            function unauthorized() {
                return throwError({ status: 401, error: { message: 'Unauthorised' } });
            }
    
            function error(message) {
                return throwError({ error: { message } });
            }
    
            function isLoggedIn() {
                return headers.get('Authorization') === 'Bearer fake-jwt-token';
            }
    
            function idFromUrl() {
                const urlParts = url.split('/');
                return parseInt(urlParts[urlParts.length - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    export const fakeBackendProvider = {
        // use fake backend in place of Http service for backend-less development
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: FakeBackendInterceptor,
        multi: true
    };
```

The SignUp Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      userName: ['', Validators.required],
      password: [null,[ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
    })
  }

  get firstName() { return this.registerForm.get('firstName') }
  get lastName() { return this.registerForm.get('lastName') }
  get userName() { return this.registerForm.get('userName') }
  get password() { return this.registerForm.get('password') }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) return;
      this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(
        data => {
           console.log(data)
        },
        error => {
           console.log(error)
        });
     
  }
```

And the service:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   register(credentials){
    console.log(credentials)
    return this.http.post(`/users/register`, credentials)
  }
```

And this is a snapshot of the console

[image: snapshot]

I haven't implemented all features, a message service, for example, but my question is, why do I get this response from the backend? Shouldn't I get a 200 status, as the register function is set to do it so? Note: the app.module is correctly set up, as the fakebackend is registered. Also if I try to fetch the users with this set up, I get a 401, which is correct because I'm not logged in, therefore the interceptor is working. Can someone help me out?

Comment: maybe you should send to http only plain object, not the form.value - I recommend to create new class Credentials with only this 4 fields (name, lastname,....) and pass to http only object of this class

Comment: ive done that already; I created an object on the submit method with all credentials, with 2, 3...etc and it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, you are using `userName`, whereas in the interceptor you are checking for `username`. If you were to clear your localStorage in browser, you would probably notice that the first time it works! Why... ?

Okay, so first time your array would be empty:

```ts
let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];
```

so if you type for username `test`, your payload would look like...

```ts
{ userName: 'test' }
```

NOTICE the uppercase `N`....so this passes:

```ts
if (users.find(x => x.username === user.username)) {
  return error('Username "' + user.username + '" is already taken');
}
```

since initially the array is empty.

Then you do this:

```ts
 user.id = users.length ? Math.max(...users.map(x => x.id)) + 1 : 1;
 users.push(user);
 localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
```

so what you now have stored in `users`, is

```ts
[{userName: 'test'}]
```

Now it won't pass the second time! Since `find` will now compare `undefined` with `undefined` as `username` property does not exist in either of the objects you are comparing in `find`.... and `undefined === undefined` is truthy and it will therefore return the first item in your `users` array.

Change your comparison to:

```ts
if (users.find(x => x.userName === user.userName))
```

and it will work correctly. Oooooor change the form control name to `username`...

Comment: it was that kind of rookie mistake...I really apreciate your answer, thanks!

Comment: welcome, glad I could help. And yeah, we all make rookie mistakes sometimes!